# How to set the correct environment variable for python scripts?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, modulenotfounderror

I have been trying to add several paths to environment variable in windows-10 but still repeatedly getting Module not found error?

[Mycurrent path to envirionment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyuAS.png)

when I try to run my training script I get Module not found error.

[error while executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q4jT.png)

Please help me to add correct path to envirionment so that I would not get "module not found error" ever again.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). Additionally, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

you can give the path to python script like this

```
<python installation path>\Scripts\
```

you can check the python installation path in windows by entering this command in cmd.

```
where python
```

Comment: I have already added python path to default path variable.I've created a new path for this project named PYTHONPROJECT and added to default path as %PYTHONPATH%.Is that necessary?

Comment: no not required, that  error  tells you that, there is no module installed with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a pretty complex directory structure. I wonder whether the fact you have a subdirectory with the same name (`regression_model`) as its parent is causing problems?

In general what you need to make the following happen:

- the module you want to import should be a directory with an `__init__.py` file inside it
- the parent directory of the module directory should be in the pythonpath

You could try renaming one of the directories and simplifying what's in the environment variable to match the above.

If that doesn't work

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

to check what the script thinks is in the pythonpath.

(you can even try using `sys.path.append` within the script to put the right thing into the path if all else fails! Might help with debugging.)